# Regex for parsing figure references

Tags: php, regex, reference

I'm trying to create a regex to parse figures references inside a text. I must match at least these cases:
Fig* 1, 2 and 3 (not only 3, any number)

Fig* 1-3

Fig* 1 and 2

Fig* 1

Fig* 1 to 4

So I tried the following regex:

```
(Fig[a-zA-Z.]*)(\s(\d(,|\s)* )+|\d\s|and\s\d|\s\d-\d|\s\d)*
```

The best result would be having the numbers separated, but having the match I can just clean up the result and parse the numbers.
But I just can't seem to be able to parse that "1 to 4". Also, this regex seems not optmized at all. Any ideas?

Here is a sample: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Zj

Comment: Casimirs' answer was the best option, since it brings the numbers separated, but Alberto's answer was quite nice as well. Sin's answer didn't work on PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(Fig(?:ures?|s\.)) (\d+(?:(?:-|, | (?:and|to) )\d+)*)
```

If you need more flexibility, you can replace spaces with `\h+` or `\h*`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(Fig.*) ((\d( to | and |-)\d)|\d)|(\d,\d and \d)
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**
I see my previous regex didn't work.

Atempting redemption, I offer two alternatives that do work -

**1.**
Using Multi-Line mode - This uses the \G anchor which provides a means
to get an aligned and trimmed output suitable for array

```
 #  '/(^Fig[a-zA-Z.]*\h+|(?!^)\G)(?(?<=\d)\h*,\h*)(\d+)(?|\h*(-)\h*(\d+)|\h+(and)\h+(\d+)|\h+(to)\h+(\d+))?/'

 (                           # (1 start)
      ^ Fig [a-zA-Z.]* \h+        #  Fig's
   |                            # or,
      (?! ^ )                     # Start at the end of last match
      \G 
 )                           # (1 end)

 (?(?<= \d )                 # Conditional, if previous digit
      \h* , \h*                   # Require a comma
 )                           # End conditional

 ( \d+ )                     # (2), Digit
 (?|                         # Branch reset (optionally, one of the (-|and|to) \d forms)
      \h* 
      ( - )                       # (3), '-'
      \h* 
      ( \d+ )                     # (4), Digit
   |  \h+ 
      ( and )                     # (3), 'and'
      \h+ 
      ( \d+ )                     # (4), Digit
   |  \h+ 
      ( to )                      # (3), 'to'
      \h+ 
      ( \d+ )                     # (4), Digit
 )?
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;
$str = <DATA>;
while ($str =~ /(^Fig[a-zA-Z.]*\h+|(?!^)\G)(?(?<=\d)\h*,\h*)(\d+)(?|\h*(-)\h*(\d+)|\h+(and)\h+(\d+)|\h+(to)\h+(\d+))?/mg)
{
   length($1) ?
   print "'$1'\t'$2'\t'$3'\t'$4'\n" :
   print "'$1'\t\t'$2'\t'$3'\t'$4'\n" ;

}
__DATA__
Figs. 1, 2, 3 and 4
Figures 1, 2
Figs. 1 and 2
Figure 1-3
Figure 1 to 3
Figure 1
```

Output >>

```
'Figs. '        '1'     ''      ''
''              '2'     ''      ''
''              '3'     'and'   '4'
'Figures '      '1'     ''      ''
''              '2'     ''      ''
'Figs. '        '1'     'and'   '2'
'Figure '       '1'     '-'     '3'
'Figure '       '1'     'to'    '3'
'Figure '       '1'     ''      ''
```

**2.** Using Multi-Line mode - This matches entire line, where capture group 1 contains 'Figs',
group 2 contains **all** the number forms

```
 #  '/^(Fig[a-zA-Z.]*\h+)((?(?<=\d)\h*,\h*|\d+(?:\h*-\h*\d+|\h+and\h+\d+|\h+to\h+\d+)?)+)\h*$/'

 ^ 
 ( Fig [a-zA-Z.]* \h+ )      # (1), Fig's
 (                           # (2 start), All the num's
      (?(?<= \d )                 # Conditional, if previous digit
           \h* , \h*                   # Require a comma 
        |                            # or
           \d+                         # Require a digit
           (?:                         # (and optionally, one of the \d (-|and|to) \d forms)
                \h* - \h* \d+ 
             |  \h+ and \h+ \d+ 
             |  \h+ to \h+ \d+ 
           )?
      )+                          # End conditional, do many times
 )                           # (2 end)
 \h* 
 $
```